# Django: How to amend a model being created?

Tags: django, django-models, model

```
class Timeline(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=256)
    # ...

class User(models.Model):
    main_timeline = models.OneToOneField('Timeline', related_name='holder_user', null=False)
    # ...
```

When creating a user, I want a new timeline to be created automatically and assigned to `main_timeline` field.

So far, the best solution I have is not to use `User.objects.create()` directly but instead wrap it into another method.

Are there other solutions?

Comment: It seems that I can just override `__init__()` and this will automatically change `User.objects.create()`. Right?

Comment: But https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects advises against overriding `__init__()`. How should I take this advice?

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the `save` method on the `User` model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

Or else, use a `pre_save` signal:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save

Example:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save)
def create_timeline_for_user(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.pk is None:
        timeline = Timeline.objects.create(name='whatever')
        instance.timeline = timeline
    return instance
```

You could use a very similar pattern (check for pk, if not present yet then create a timeline and associate it) in the `save` method itself.

Note: The correct terminology here is that an 'instance' is being created, not a model.

Comment: I expect that this won't work. `User()` constructor without `main_timeline=` argument will raise an exception because `main_timeline` has no default value

Comment: or does the check happen in `save()`, not in constructor?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? All you need to do is type `user = User()` in a python shell. Anyway, to give you the answer, the check is at the database level, so it happens on save.

Comment: As a general tip, in 5 years or so of Django work, I've almost never (maybe once) had to think about the model constructor. Unless you are doing something very exotic, you can be sure that the provided public API methods on the Django classes will give you everything you need.